# Noveria: Lorik Qui'in - Broken Quest?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect

After completing the main questline in Noveria, I still have one quest in my Journal which seems like it cannot be finished.  That is the quest involving Lorik Qui'in.

Early on, I found that I needed to get a garage pass to proceed outside of the Noveria port.  Gianna told me that Lorik Qui'in might be able to assist me.  At this point, the quest "Noveria: Lorik Qui'in" was added to my Journal.

On my way to meet Lorik, I ran into Mallene Calis.  However, I refused her quest on ethical grounds.  "Noveria: Espionage" was added to my Journal, and instantly marked as completed - noting my refusal.

When I spoke to Lorik, I did not see any conversation paths that appeared to be leading in the direction I needed them to.  After exploring all my options, I went to wander about in search of some trigger that would open up a new line of conversation.

During my wanderings, I discovered the "Noveria: Smuggling" quest.  I resolved this towards the end of receiving a garage pass.  No longer requiring Lorik's services, I've since moved on to complete the remainder of my primary mission on Noveria.

However, I now have the "Noveria: Lorik Qui'in" quest left unresolved in my Journal.  Whenever I go back to talk to him, I'm not given any conversation options - immediately upon starting the conversation, my character excuses themselves from it.

Is there no way for me to get this quest cleared from my Journal, now?

*NOTE:  I'm on the PS3, so any console commands or other workarounds that are PC-specific will not be feasible for me.*

Comment: The only [Lorik Qui'in](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Lorik_Qui%27in) bug I know of is the unlimited paragon/renegade bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.  This quest will remain open and unfinished for the remainder of your game.  The only way I've found to close it is to actually go through with it before receiving the garage pass from the administrator.